# How can I get into C++ graphics library?

Tags: c++, graphics

I have been programming for a year so far and I know 2 languages: C and C++. I've covered the basics, I've written functional windows programs, and I've written complicated bits of code. When I was using Turbo C for learning the C language I noticed a library called "Graphics.h". I've looked it up and I received amazing examples of graphics manipulation. My question is straightforward. How can I get started with learning graphics in C++? Is there a good tutorial that covers it all up?

Comment: What kind of applications involving do you have in mind? A graphics library primarily designed for 2D looks very different from one designed for 3D. Also, it will be platform specific unless you use a cross-platform library.

Comment: I'm talking generally, 2D graphics but I'm willing to learn both.

Comment: Did you want to learn how to make a graphics library yourself such as drawing and filling shapes on a bitmap plane, or pointers to interesting libraries that are worth learning?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Back in the graphics.h days each compiler had it's own limited graphics library.

Now you program to either DirectX (Microsoft) or OpenGL (everywhere). After a few years of being sidelined to high-end Unix cad OpenGL/OpenGLEs is making a big splash  on mobile devices

For a list of books see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926357/c-opengl-books

One warning - there are a lot of 20year old out of date opengl tutroials on the web - start here [An intro to modern OpenGL](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-1:-The-Graphics-Pipeline.html).

ps. Some of the maths of 3D graphics (matrix transformations etc) might be beyond what you have covered in school but it's very easy - you just have to sit down and work through it. But do go through all the math until you understand it, you will need it!

Comment: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ is also very good.

Answer (score 11):

`graphics.h` isn't relevant to anything. It's been 10-15 years since that header was useful. The same for the Turbo C compiler.

You need to upgrade your compiler to, let's say, Visual Studio 2010 Express (free) for Windows. Then you can look at things like Direct2D and GDI+ for 2D graphics.

Comment: I don't think you have completely understood my question.. I have been using Turbo C for training in C, I don't use that anymore. Logically, if I made functional programs I used Visual studio 2010 (not the express version, the full one). Graphics.h was just a  reference, not the question itself. I'm asking for a starting point for graphics in C++, perhaps some tutorials or articles, or a brief explanation of what I could search.

Comment: @ThePlan: "things like Direct2D and GDI+ for 2D graphics".

Answer (score 6):

Graphics typycally require some knowledge about platform specific interfaces, some general math, and eventually some typical pattern.

You can start from the [Widows GDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and GDI+) and from the [X Window system](http://tronche.com/gui/x/) (for Unix/Linux)

and move to 3d with [openGL](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lessons_01__05/22004/)(every platform) or [Direct3d](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Tutorial11/tutorials.aspx)(on Windows)

Answer (score 5):

A simple graphics library is the [Simple Fast Multimedia Library](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) for C++ which is cross platform, modern and very easy.

> SFML provides a simple interface to the various components of your PC, to ease the development of games and multimedia applications. It is composed of five modules: system, window, graphics, audio and network.
>
> Discover their features more in detail in the [tutorials](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials.php) and the [API documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation.php)...
>
> With SFML, your application can compile and run out of the box on the most common operating systems: Windows, Linux, Mac OS X and soon Android & iOS.
>
> Pre-compiled SDKs for your favorite OS are available on the [download page](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php)...
>
> SFML has official bindings for the C and .Net languages. And thanks to its active community, it is also available in many other languages such as Java, Ruby, Python, Go, and more.
>
> Learn more about them on the [bindings page](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/bindings.php)...

Alternatively you could use OpenGl (I would prefer due to platform independence) or DirectX.